# Sending masked data from web socket server to web socket client

Tags: c, sockets, encoding, web

I have developed the following C code to mask data before sending back to web server client which is java script running on Firefox browser using RFC 6455 Protocol.
However I am facing problem as I am not able to see anything on client side.
Some say that its not necessary to mask data when sending from server to client. Is that true ? I can't see that working in my case.
Let me know if my question is ambiguous somewhere.
Thanks for your kind help.

```
char frame[131],message[360];
strcpy(message,"Server here !");                
frame[0] = '\x81';
frame[1] = 128 + strlen(message);
frame[2] = '\x00';
frame[3] = '\x00';
frame[4] = '\x00';
frame[5] = '\x00';
snprintf(frame+6, 124, "%s", message);
printf("%s", frame);
n = write(newsockfd, frame, strlen(frame));
```

Comment: That doesn't do any RFC 6455 masking that I can see. Where are the XORs?

Comment: I was firstly trying to send unmasked data to see if its working as I read in RFC that data from server can be sent without any masking. Would be glad if you can point out how can I mask and how to we decide masking bits ?

Comment: You question is entitled 'sending masked data'. Your problem doesn't even attempt it. Mistyped questions don't help anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `strlen` function to get the length of anything but a C-style string. Your frame is not a C-style string. The length of the frame is `6 + strlen(message)`, not `strlen(frame)`.

This is also why `printf("%s", frame);` didn't work. The `%s` format specifier is for C-style strings, which your frame isn't.

This assumes your message is a C-style string. If not, you have other bugs since you use `strlen` to compute its length in the initializer for `frame[1]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Got you !
I was making mistake by using strlen(frame) as soon as I replaced it with 6+strlen(message) it worked exactly how I wanted (unmasked data)
Can you help me how can I send masked data to a client which client is able to decode (RFC 6455)?

Comment: Just follow the specification. If you run into trouble, ask specific questions. (Or look around for an implementation someone else did.)

Answer (score 1):

The length of the frame is not given by strlen(), because of the embedded nulls. Add the message length to the frame prefix length. But where is the masking?

Comment: Thanks.
Can you help me with masking according to RFC 6455 ? I was firstly trying to send unmasked data at first to see if its working.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why would you want to mask the frames sent to the client?

The [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) says the following:

A server MUST NOT mask any frames that it sends to
the client. A client MUST close a connection if it detects a masked
frame.

Check section 5.1 for more details.